# how to open the pdf document inside web view using flutter

Tags: flutter

I am creating an app using flutter. I am struggling to open the Portable Document Format inside the web view using flutter. Please help to resolve this

> body: SafeArea( 
>             child: WebView(
>               initialUrl: pdf filePath,
>               javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
>               onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
>                 _webViewController = webViewController;
>                 _webViewController.clearCache();
>                _webViewController.reload();
>               },
>             ),
>         ),

my code

```
    SafeArea( child: WebView( initialUrl: filePath, javascriptMode: 
JavascriptMode.unrestricted, 
onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) { _webViewController = webViewController; 
_webViewController.clearCache(); 
_webViewController.reload(); }, ), ),
```

Comment: add some code please

Comment: @Ggriffo please find the below code
body: SafeArea( 
          child: WebView(            
            initialUrl: filePath,
            javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
            onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
              _webViewController = webViewController;
              _webViewController.clearCache();
             _webViewController.reload();
            },
          ),
      ),

Comment: always add your code to question ,not in comments,:

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue before and I used this method to solve that. In the initialUrl you can check if the url is a pdf link and use google doc to open it.

```
initialUrl:  widget.link!.indexOf('.pdf') != -1 ? 'https://docs.google.com/gview? 
                    embedded=true&url=${widget.link}'
                    : widget.link!
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import 'dart: html' as html;
html.window.open ('http: ///www.website.com/document.pdf');
```

You can refer: https://pub.dev/packages/pdf

Comment: This is web only